# how installing curl extention in my wamp 2.2

Tags: php, curl

i use wamp server 2.2 , and i want using web service in my project but i should installing curl extension in my wamp.
i search 'curl' in php.ini file and i see this line.

> extension=php_curl.dll

this show curl is install but i face this message in my page :

> HTTP Error: The PHP cURL Extension is required for HTTPS or NLTM.  You will need to re-build or update your PHP to included cURL

how i doing?
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think its basicly saying you PHP build is not compatible with cURL. You could try using Xampp instead.

http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html

Comment: is there another way , because this solution need giving backup from all project in my wamp.